Map top strip of laptop touchpad to key actions in x.org
I would like to map taps to the top strip of my laptop's touchpad to key presses or other actions.
For example, if I tap on the very top of the touchpad while typing, then I might get a backspace, or a return, or "open a Terminal", or something more exotic.
Is this possible, and if so, how?
